# How to Open terminal and Embed Terminal To Nautilus File Browser?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

Never thought I might have to ask THIS, but this is my first linux installation, and I can't find the Terminal. How do I open it?

And is there any way to open the bash from the file explorer, starting with the file explorer's path as working path?

Thank you,
Simon L.

Comment: I assume you mean the command line terminal? If so, it's in the launcher menu. In Unity I believe you'll find it if you type 'terminal' into the launcher search window (same goes for KDE).

Comment: [This link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/10/enabling-open-command-prompt-from.html) might help. You need to install "nautilus-open-terminal" and "nautilus-terminal" plugins.

Answer (score 4):

The way I do it is to install the `nautilus-open-terminal` package, (and then restart nautilus):

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
killall nautilus
```

Then you can right click on a folder, or in empty space and you will have the option to "Open in Terminal". If you select that option a new terminal will be opened with the working directory set to that folder.

[image: nautilus screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

- To open terminal press `super key` or click on ubuntu icon on the left side then type `terminal`
  [image]
- To Embed Terminal To Nautilus File Browser (explorer)

You will need `Nautilus Terminal`

You can install Nautilus Terminal using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/flozz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-terminal
```

Once installed, Open terminal and use this command to restart Nautilus to apply the changes.

```
nautilus -q
```

You will see the embed terminal look like this

[image]

In case you would like to remove this extension, use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-terminal
sudo apt-get udpate
```

Comment: Is there one that embeds a terminal for orthodox file manager?

Answer (score 0):

to open terminal (and start a bash session) you can:

- press `cntrl+alt+t`
- press `super` then type `terminal`
- open dash by clicking on it in the launcher and type `terminal`